# How do I pass an array or list as a parameter to a PowerShell function?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am writing a PowerShell script to get a list of certificates which are getting expired within 30 days. The script is working, but the problem is there are too many app and pres servers, and I want to minimize the script code. My function is:

```
function CheckCert($ComputerNames)
{
    $deadline = (Get-Date).AddDays($global:threshold) # Set deadline date
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerNames { Dir Cert:\LocalMachine\My } |
        foreach {
            If ($_.NotAfter -le $deadline)
            {
                $_ | Select Issuer, Subject, NotAfter, @{Label="Expires In (Days)";Expression={($_.NotAfter - (Get-Date)).Days}}
            }
        }
}
```

And I am calling this function like:

```
Switch ($xMenu1)
{
    1 {CheckCert -ComputerNames "CUKIRUNCSVR0242"}
    2 {CheckCert}
    3 {CheckCert}
    ...
```

**I want to pass ComputerNames like serv1, serv2, serv3 and this number of servers cound vary from 1 to 6 depending upon the option selected from menu. **OR** Can I define a list of servers of different envirinments and pass the list name as parameter and modify my CheckCert function to loop through for each server and get the expired certificate details?

```
Switch ($xMenu1)
{
    1 {CheckCert -ComputerNames CIT_envList}
    2 {CheckCert -ComputerNames SIT_envList}
    3 {CheckCert -ComputerNames Prod_envList}
    ...
```

And their server lists are something like:

```
CIT_envList = serv1, serv2

SIT_envList = serv1, serv2, serv3,

PROD_envList = serv1, serv2, serv3, serv4
```

Comment: Invoke-command can take an array of computernames as an argument.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this:

```
function CheckCert([string[]]$ComputerNames)
{
    $deadline = (Get-Date).AddDays($global:threshold) # Set deadline date
    foreach ($computer in $ComputerNames)
    {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer { Dir Cert:\LocalMachine\My } |
        foreach {
            If ($_.NotAfter -le $deadline)
            {
                $_ | Select Issuer, Subject, NotAfter, @{N="Expires In (Days)";E={($_.NotAfter - (Get-Date)).Days}}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to pass values in the variable $ComputerNames="adf","fdf","sdffd","adsfad",adsfasf" like this?

Answer (score 4):

Working with PS 4.0 or later, it´s possible to define as `CheckCert([array]$ComputerNames)` as well.