# Pass an array list using IntelliSense

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Good afternoon, all!

Is there a way I may be able to pass an array using an IntelliSense option?
As in, passing the contents of the array. Ive attempted the following but, im not too sure on what I can do next to make it work (if its even possible).

```
ENUM GroupsList{
    Group1
    Group2
    Group3
    }

$Group1 = @(
    "Name 1",
    "Name 2",
    "Name 3"
    )


$Group2 = @(
    "Name 4",
    "Name 5",
    "Name 6"
    )


$Group3 = @(
    "Name 7",
    "Name 8",
    "Name 9"
    )

Function Add-Groups{
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [GroupsList]
        $GroupName
        )

Foreach($Group in $GroupName){
    "$Group"}
    }
```

Please note that I'm just experimenting; no real reason why I've come up with this.

`Add-Groups [-GroupName] <string>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656450/how-do-i-pass-an-array-or-list-as-a-parameter-to-a-powershell-function

Comment: So it cant be done using IntelliSense? What theyre doing in that question seems to just be passing the array as an array, not an IntelliSense option.

Comment: Intellisense is code auto completion, i do not understand what you want to do ?

Comment: To pass the contents of an array using Intellisense. Meaning, if i have a validateset of the Array Names, id like to pass whats inside the Array, not the name.

Comment: you pass the array by code to a function, Intellisense has nothing to do with it. Intellisense simply helps you writing the code ( by auto completion), however you can simply overwrite any suggestions Intellisense makes

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_code_completion

Comment: I don't think you understand what im trying to say.

Comment: I'm looking to reference the array by the option ive selected. If I type `Add-Groups -GroupName Group3`, is there no way to get the listed strings in the array?

Comment: I am not so deep in the Intellisense details because Intellisense is only a helper tool

Comment: im aware of that lol, i guess i just worded it wrong (sorry!). Anyways, i figured it out; talking to you helped me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's me.

I figured it out. I just ended up using the `switch` statement to reference back to the array depending on the choice.

```
$Group1 = @(
    "Name 1",
    "Name 2",
    "Name 3"
    )


$Group2 = @(
    "Name 4",
    "Name 5",
    "Name 6"
    )


$Group3 = @(
    "Name 7",
    "Name 8",
    "Name 9"
    )


Function Add-Groups{
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [validateset("Group1","Group2","Group3")]
        [string[]]$GroupName
        )
$Groups = switch -Exact ($GroupName){
        "Group1" {$Group1}
        "Group2" {$Group2}
        "Group3" {$Group3}
        }



Foreach($Group in $Groups){
"$Group"             
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Add-Groups -GroupName Group3
Name 7
Name 8
Name 9
```